# Display 7 record for each page in a loop

Tags: javascript, html

Please I have an object and I want to display 7 (A specified number) records for each page using javascript Bellow is my what i have tried but not working as i want.

The idea is just to display 7 (A specified number) of data from my object irrespective of the length and display 7 per page inside the page tag (Note the `<page size="A4">`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Recharge Card Printing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>
        body {
        background: rgb(204,204,204); 
        }
        page {
        background: white;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        }
        page[size="A4"] {  
        width: 21cm;
        height: 29.7cm; 
        }
        page[size="A4"][layout="portrait"] {
        width: 29.7cm;
        height: 21cm;  
        }
        @media print {
        body, page {
            margin: 0;
            box-shadow: 0;
        }
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

         <form>
             <div class="form-group">
           
               <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
             </div>
           </form>
        </div>
    </div>
        
    <div class="content" id="content">

    </div>
       
    </div>
    <!-- <page size="A4">A4</page> -->
    <!-- <page size="A4" layout="portrait">A4 portrait</page> -->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        let myObj = [{"transaction_id":2148502,"pin":"5546264569082316","serial":"20269459506874475340"},{"transaction_id":2148503,"pin":"5428411501366197","serial":"20269459506874475341"},{"transaction_id":2148504,"pin":"5886462495344314","serial":"20269459506874475342"},{"transaction_id":2148505,"pin":"5754893044887194","serial":"20269459506874475343"},{"transaction_id":2148506,"pin":"5575099609378880","serial":"20269459506874475344"},{"transaction_id":2148507,"pin":"5962838201364936","serial":"20269459506874475345"},{"transaction_id":2148508,"pin":"5629460215606835","serial":"20269459506874475346"},{"transaction_id":2148509,"pin":"5251626330904232","serial":"20269459506874475347"},{"transaction_id":2148510,"pin":"5473983858022316","serial":"20269459506874475348"},{"transaction_id":2148511,"pin":"5035915948023649","serial":"20269459506874475349"},{"transaction_id":2148512,"pin":"5994013966683499","serial":"20269459506874475350"},{"transaction_id":2148513,"pin":"5567994838392524","serial":"20269459506874475351"},{"transaction_id":2148514,"pin":"5266652700904545","serial":"20269459506874475352"},{"transaction_id":2148515,"pin":"5911997159539892","serial":"20269459506874475353"},{"transaction_id":2148516,"pin":"5968096536718357","serial":"20269459506874475354"},{"transaction_id":2148517,"pin":"5702900732523495","serial":"20269459506874475355"},{"transaction_id":2148518,"pin":"5640011176137451","serial":"20269459506874475356"},{"transaction_id":2148519,"pin":"5424828701030695","serial":"20269459506874475357"},{"transaction_id":2148520,"pin":"5274502344855426","serial":"20269459506874475358"},{"transaction_id":2148521,"pin":"5932591029180138","serial":"20269459506874475359"},{"transaction_id":2148522,"pin":"5691950647991301","serial":"20269459506874475360"},{"transaction_id":2148523,"pin":"5717637005294871","serial":"20269459506874475361"},{"transaction_id":2148524,"pin":"5030550779696386","serial":"20269459506874475362"},{"transaction_id":2148525,"pin":"5982485251766928","serial":"20269459506874475363"},{"transaction_id":2148526,"pin":"5326364724214037","serial":"20269459506874475364"},{"transaction_id":2148527,"pin":"5217898560290446","serial":"20269459506874475365"},{"transaction_id":2148528,"pin":"5664116975465082","serial":"20269459506874475366"},{"transaction_id":2148529,"pin":"5311560166664051","serial":"20269459506874475367"},{"transaction_id":2148530,"pin":"5567923108676950","serial":"20269459506874475368"},{"transaction_id":2148531,"pin":"5924484969131643","serial":"20269459506874475369"}]


        for(var key in myObj){
            console.log(myObj[key].pin)
            const div = document.createElement('div');
    

            div.className = 'row';
            
            div.innerHTML = `
                ${key==7?'<page size="A4">':''}
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    ${myObj[key].pin}
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    ${myObj[key].pin}
                </div>
                ${key==7?'</page>':''}

            `;

            document.getElementById('content').appendChild(div);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So if the data is up to 7 in the loop, the next 7 data displays on the next page.
I will appreciate the help, please.

Answer (score 0):

This way, on every 7th record, you can add logic:

```
div.innerHTML = `
            ${(key>=7 && (key%7 == 0) )?'<page size="A4">':''}
            <div class="col-md-6">
                ${myObj[key].pin}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                ${myObj[key].pin}
            </div>
            ${(key>=7 && (key%7 == 0))?'</page>':''}

        `;
```